# Docker compose config, --env.file, docker pull and docker stack deploy

Tags: docker-compose, docker-stack, docker-pull

I have a problem with these docker commands. I want join the docker compose command to docker stack deploy:

I have written the following instructions in my script:

```
    docker-compose --env-file $HOME/myinstallation/yml/env config

    docker-compose pull

    docker stack deploy --compose-file $HOME/myinstallation/yml/docker-compose.yml myinstallation
```

The first command it works and my compose is pardes correctly, but compose pull doesn't woork.

I have thise error:

*WARNING: "The service variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string"*. And then it pull the latest of my service:

maybe my declaration of tags is not correct?

in my docker compose my service has these tag

```
    version: "3.6"

    networks:
      mynetwork:
        external: true
        name: mynetwork

    services:

      myservice:
        deploy:
          mode: replicated
          placement:
            constraints:
              - node.role == manager
          replicas: 1
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
        image: myinstallation/test:${service}
        networks:
           -mynetwork
        ports:
           88:80
```

and in my env file i have setted the variable in this mode:

```
    service=1.0.2
```

Any idea? Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `docker-compose --env-file $HOME/myinstallation/yml/env config` won't overwrite your targeted compose file.

I would suggest trying to pipe the output of `docker-compose --env-file $HOME/myinstallation/yml/env config`

into

`docker stack deploy ..`

This way

```
docker-compose --env-file $HOME/myinstallation/yml/env config |
docker stack deploy --compose-file - myinstallation
```

Comment: One issue I'm seeing - the config generates the ports as:
`- 8080:8080` - translates to 
` ports: ...   published: "8080"`

And then when running this i'm getting error:
`services.myService.ports.0.published must be a integer`